# correlate and sync block in gnuradio

Tags: synchronization, block, gnuradio

In the documentation of "correlate and sync block", it says, this block outputs the "Output stream that just passes the input complex samples". Does this "output stream" delete the preamble in the input complex samples and only output the samples after the preamble?

Answer (score 1):

No. The wording of the documentation is unambiguous: it is just a copy of the input samples.

Also, "data" is a few steps ahead in your demodulation after you've done a correlation synchronization – how should that block already know anything about data?

Comment: Input could sometimes mean the actual data, and it sometimes means the preamble + data based on the context, isn't it?

Comment: No. The wording of the documentation in my humble opinion doesn't allow for that interpretation, as I already pointed out in my answer.

Comment: This is not a place for argument. Again, understanding on some wording depends on the background, experience, or the conventional handling of an input sequence in a traditional demodulation process.

Comment: If this is not a place for argument, then why are you arguing my expressed opinion? "just passes the input samples" really **is** unambiguous. It is a clear sentence, it doesn't depend.